# When the word "our" is unstressed, is it pronounced like /ʌɹ/ or /əɹ/?

Tags: pronunciation

When the word "our" is unstressed, is it pronounced like /ʌɹ/ or /əɹ/? For example: https://vocaroo.com/i/s0uXE3Gaahqm

Comment: I'm not sure the word "our" ***can*** be completely "unstressed". I certainly can't imagine the vowel sound being reduced to a schwa the way ***your*** can be (in eye-dialect, *Gimmie all **yer** money!*, for example).

Comment: This is _highly_ region-dependent since "our" is pronounced quite differently in various Am.E accents (Midwestern, Southern, and New England) and various Br.E accents (RP, Scots, ...).

Comment: @TypeIA Thanks for your comment. How is it pronounced in an American accent? Can you please listen to the voice recording? Thanks.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for your comment. How about in an American accent?

Answer (score 1):

When writing / / you are indicating a phonemic transcription. In unstressed position, the vowels [] are not phonemically distingushed. They are treated as variant productions of the same vowel.  Different transcriptions may use /ʌ/ or /ə/ to indicate this vowel. However "our" is normally transcribed as /aʊə/ at least for the British pronunciation.